# How do I pass a 2D vec as a slice to a function?

Tags: rust

For one dimension the code mockup is:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    print_it(&a); // :)
}

fn print_it(p: &[usize]) {
    println!("{:?}", p);
}
```

I try to apply the equivalent logic for a two dimensional vector and it doesn't work

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: Vec<Vec<usize>> = vec![
        vec![1,2,3,4,],
        vec![5,6,7,8,],
    ];
    print_it(&a); // :( expected slice `[&[usize]]`, found struct `Vec`
}

fn print_it(p: &[&[usize]] ) {
    println!("{:?}", p);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read the full error message: `note: expected reference '&[&[usize]]' found reference '&Vec<Vec<usize>>'` The function expects a slice of slices of `usize`, but you're passing it a reference to a `Vec` of `Vec` of `usize`.

Comment: The message say that the type is wrong, of course. That's what I don't understand. Which is the right type to answer my question?

Comment: You would need a `Vec<&[usize]>` to make that work, or change `print_it` to accept `&[Vec<usize>]` (or even `&Vec<Vec<usize>>`)

Comment: &[Vec<usize>] is ok. But, could I convert the inner vector to another slice?, i.e, slice of slices

Answer (score 5):

This conversion is not possible without extra work. From the official documentation of the [slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html) type:

> A dynamically-sized view into a contiguous sequence, [T]. Contiguous here means that elements are laid out so that every element is the same distance from its neighbors.

That means the memory that is pointed to, looks like this:

```
| T | T | ... | T |
```

> Slices are a view into a block of memory represented as a pointer and a length.

That means that the type `[&[usize]]` could look something like this in memory:

```
| pointer, length | pointer, length | ... | pointer, length |
```

You, however, have a vector of vectors. A vector has a pointer to its allocated memory and two `usize`s, one for the length and one for the capacity. A `[Vec<T>]` is therefore

```
| pointer, length, capacity | pointer, length, capacity | ... | pointer, length, capacity |
```

The `Vec<Vec<T>>` has this layout in its internal buffer too. Since the latter layout of pointer-length pairs is not contiguous (the space for the capacity `usize` is inbetween), we cannot just reinterpret a pointer to that memory as if it was a `&[&[T]]`.

---

If you really need the 2D slice, you have to allocate a new buffer that has the pointer-length layout:

```rust
let v: Vec<Vec<usize>> = todo!();
let slice2d: Vec<&[usize]> = v.iter().map(Vec::as_slice).collect();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6e7abfbc56ea14eef1d4a056166b5b7f)

If you just don't want to restrict your function signature to `Vec`, you could make it more generic:

```rust
use std::ops::Index;

fn print_it<I>(p: &[I])
where
    I: Index<usize, Output = usize>,
{
    println!("{:?}", p[0][0]);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=23f17235a4ce8c3ddbe344568793e5b6)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not in the function signature. You need to have a `Vec<&[usize]>` so it can finally be a `&[&[usize]]`. For example, taking the slices and collecting them in another vector:

```rust
let a_refs: Vec<&[usize]> = a.iter().map(|v| v.as_slice()).collect();
```

Full example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: Vec<Vec<usize>> = vec![
        vec![1,2,3,4,],
        vec![5,6,7,8,],
    ];
    let a_refs: Vec<&[usize]> = a.iter().map(|v| v.as_slice()).collect();
    print_it(&a_refs); // :( expected slice `[&[usize]]`, found struct `Vec`
}

fn print_it(p: &[&[usize]] ) {
    println!("{:?}", p);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c7f5ff6ba90e9e031b7c76791c27f211)

Notice that the new vector only contains references to the slices of the originals vectors.